# Inside Framelayout i have 1 cardview and an image view. I want the image view over the card view. What i want to do

Tags: android, android-framelayout, cardview

I was trying to make an image view over the card view. So I used Framelayout. Inside that i added 1 cardview after that I added an image view. If I use a LinearLayout instead of cardview the image view views over the linearlayout. But if I use card view the image view is not getting over the card view. Please help me ...
[I have shown what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzdTn.jpg)

Comment: pl, show us what you have tried ?

Comment: Hi Nandakumar. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please paste your code directly into question. Links to screenshots sometimes expire. :)

Answer (score 1):

put your card view inside AnyLayout like LinerarLayout

```
<FrameLayout>
 <LinearLayout>
   <CardView/>
 </LinearLayout>
 <ImageView/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply. It is working great.<FrameLayout>
 <LinearLayout>
   <CardView/>
 </LinearLayout>
 <ImageView/>
</FrameLayout> This works great. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like below:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CustomGallery"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Dummy Text"
        android:gravity="center"/>

<!--  Add more Views -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">
            <!--<ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/add_menu_item_logo"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_brightness_low_24"
                />-->
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/add_menu_logo_placeholder">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_brightness_low_24"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use card view like this

```
       <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="0dp" 
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Note the important attribs are
app:cardElevation="0dp"
and android:elevation="0dp"
It will set the elevation to 0.